# Is std::async guaranteed to be called for functions returning void?

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, stdasync

I've wrote the following code to test `std::async()` on functions returning `void` with GCC 4.8.2 on Ubuntu.

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

void functionTBC()
{
    std::cerr << "Print here\n";
}

int main(void)
{
#ifdef USE_ASYNC
    auto i = std::async(std::launch::async, functionTBC);
#else
    auto i = std::async(std::launch::deferred, functionTBC);
#endif
    //i.get();
    return 0;
}
```

If `i.get();` is uncommented, the message `"Print here"` always exists; however, if `i.get();` is commented out, `"Print here"` exists if and only if `USE_ASYNC` is defined (that is, `std::launch::async` always leads to message printed out while `std::launch::deferred` never).

Is this guaranteed behavior? What's the correct way to ensure the asynchronous call returning `void` to be executed?

Comment: If you ask for a deferred launch and never call .get on that future, your function will never be executed. This has nothing to do with the function returning void or any other type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::launch::deferred` means "do not run this until I `.wait()` or `.get()`".

As you never `.get()` or `.wait()`ed, it never ran.

`void` has nothing to do with this.

For `std::launch::async`, the standard states that the returned future's destructor (`~future`) will block until the task is complete (ie, has an implicit `.wait()`).  This is violated by MSVC on purpose, because they disagreed with that design decision, and they are fighting to change the standard: in practice, this means that you cannot rely on any behavior at all from `std::launch::async` returned `future` if you want to future-proof your code.

Without implicit `wait` in `~future`, it would be indeterminate if it actually invoked the function when `main` exited.  It would either have happened, or not.  Possibly you could invoke UB by having still-active threads at the end of `main`.

You may wonder what use `deferred` has: you can use it to queue up a computation for lazy evaluation.

Comment: If I just drop the return value of `std::async()` (remove the `auto i = ` in my snippet), the `std::launch::deferred` version is still skipped. Doesn't this violate "`~future` will block until the task completes"?

Comment: "~future will block until the task completes" doesn't apply in this case, because of std::launch::deferred. Suggest you pick up a copy of Meyer's "Effective Modern C++", see Item 38.

Comment: @timrau The note about `~future` blocking only applies when you `std::async( std::launch::async`.  Note that calling `std::async( std::launch::async` without storing the return value causes it to be destroyed at the end of the statement, so the main thread blocks until the async task is complete *on that very line*.  Storing it in `auto i=` will make the block occur at the end of the scope.  Moving the returned `future` to another `future` will defer the block until the future that stores the state is finally destroyed.

Comment: @Yakk Sorry, I accidentally missed the condition  "For `std::launch::async`".

Comment: MSVC 2015's `async` [now returns blocking futures](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/06/c-14-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-visual-studio-14-ctp1.aspx), after the proposed change failed to pass in full committee.

Comment: @T.C. Did they modify the page?  I can't find either `async` or `promise` word in the link.

Comment: @cppBeginner http://web.archive.org/web/20160112225646/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/06/c-14-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-visual-studio-14-ctp1.aspx