# Fixing compiler warning C4834 - discarding return value of std::async function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, visual-studio-2019, nodiscard

I am fixing warnings in C++ codebase. There is this function that uses `std::async`, but the return `std::future` object is not captured, so the compiler is raising C4834 warning. The function is as below:

```
LONG WINAPI VexHandler(PEXCEPTION_POINTERS pExceptionPtrs)
{
    if (pExceptionPtrs->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode == EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW)
    {
        std::async(WriteMiniDumpWithActualJniContext, pExceptionPtrs);
        quick_exit(1);
    }
    else if (pExceptionPtrs->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode == EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT)
    {
        WINDUMP_IMPLEMENTATION->WriteMiniDump(pExceptionPtrs);

        string exceptionInformation = GetExceptionsInformation(pExceptionPtrs);
        throw std::runtime_error(exceptionInformation);
    }

    return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
}
```

To fix this warning I have captured the return from `std::async` and called `wait()` on that.

```
...
if (pExceptionPtrs->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode == EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW)
{
    auto ftr = std::async(WriteMiniDumpWithActualJniContext, pExceptionPtrs);
    ftr.wait();
    quick_exit(1);
}
...
```

Which way is better to fix this warning as per C++17 standard?

Alternatively I think I could have typecasted the return to `void` as below:

```
...
if (pExceptionPtrs->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode == EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW)
{
    static_cast<void>(std::async(WriteMiniDumpWithActualJniContext, pExceptionPtrs));
    quick_exit(1);
}
...
```

Comment: If you ask for work to happen in a different thread, and then wait *this* thread until it finishes, you might as do the work on this thread - skip the future *and* the await and just call that function directly. Alternatively, if that work is expensive and you want it to happen in parallel with other work, catch the future and call wait on it after the other work. It's a different question, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30535125/21311096) also applies to you

Comment: You have to understand the reason of the warning, instead of just try to silent it.

Comment: `WriteMiniDumpWithActualJniContext(pExceptionPtrs);` might be what you want.